# python Web socket component for erlang chat server?

Tags: python, django, websocket

I have external web socket server writtern in Erlang language , I need to create a python library/component for the erlang server.

My aim is if the developer need to integrate the python component with their application (eg: django project ),
just call the functions pass the parameters, the component need to handle the connections, recive the messages etc.

I don't know is it possible , please suggest me a good solution for this. Thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible.

You first need one erlang client do something like `Pid ! Message`, I think you are familiar with this, or you can use `OTP`. The client is responsible for send message from erlang client to your erlang server.

Next what you need is [Apache thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/lib/), with this, you can write a python language binding to your erlang client.

Then, user can call your python client, and the python client will use RPC to connect to your erlang client with the help of Thrift, and erlang client will send message to erlang server use `Pid ! Message` or `OTP`.